# How to access the file system in chrome os

Tags: google-chrome-os

Is it possible to have an extension read/write to/from the local file system in chrome os?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can read/write with the File API:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

and you can even hook up your extension to the file system. I've wrote about it: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/chrome-apps-web-store-and-the-new-chromeos-file-api/

Comment: @ldo Green - So unless I'm reading this wrong, I still can't access any file on the file system.  Just files within the app's sandbox.  I'm hoping to be able to access any folder/file on the file system.

Comment: So how do you program certain things for google chrome OS??? This seems like basic functionality for an operating system.

Comment: using the file API that its scope is limited to the domain it came from.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to access the root parent directory. In order to do that you'll have to put your chromebook into developer mode, and when signing in enable debugging options. That will give you the option to view and edit chromeos system files. Just be careful and make sure you create a recovery disc first.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the standard File API, but chrome provides its own proprietary fileSystem API which, in my opinion, is much easier: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem